# How to configure Windows 10 login with secure LDAP

Tags: ldap, google-sso, google-cloud-identity

Is there any way to configure windows 10 login with Google secure LDAP service?

References which I have already tried: ([LDP.exe for windows 10](https://support.google.com/cloudidentity/answer/9089736))

Can anyone help me in this

Thanks